# iPad - Recognizing specified telephone number after globally disabling

Tags: html, ipad, phone-number

I'm have webpage optimizes for iPad, and I've noticed that sometimes it recognizes my random numbers as telephone numbers. I've dealt with that with this meta:

```
<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no" />
```

and it works perfectly. But now I have kind of a problem. On one webpage, I have contact information (including telephone number), and I want that telephone number to get recognized. How can I tell iPad to recognize only that number, while ignoring all others ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly inform Safari what is a telephone link. Take a look on the [IOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html).